# Update and add new records table with join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have main table, mytable, with columns id,a,b,c,d 
and a Temp_TABLE with columns id,b,c

I want to update mytable with the values on 
temp Temp_TABLE, and if the records are not in mytable then insert them.

So far I have the following:

```
UPDATE mytable  
JOIN  
Temp_TABLE  
ON mytable.profileId = Temp_TABLE.profileId 
SET mytable.b = Temp_TABLE.b
    mytable.c = Temp_TABLE.c
```

But this only works for the first part.

How can I insert the the records from Temp_TABLE  into mytable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, use `insert on duplicate key update`.  But first you have to define the criteria for recognizing duplicates.  For that, you need a unique index (or constraint):

```
create unique index unq_mytable_profileId on mytable(profileid);
```

Then:

```
insert into mytable (profileid, b, c)
    select tt.profileid, tt.b, tt.c
    from temp_table tt
    on duplicate key update b = values(b), c = values(c);
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set b = values(b), c = values(c)' at line 4

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez . . . That was a typo.